# How to get month wise sum of data in a table

Tags: google-sheets

I have date in one column and data in another from jan 2017 to Dec 2022.
I want to find sum of data month wise.
attaching file. Currently doing it manually. Any work around, array or something. Help.

[image]

Comment: You might look into `SUMIFS`. Or a pivot table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with a QUERY like this:

```
=QUERY({INDEX(EOMONTH(A:A,0)),C:C},"SELECT Col1,Sum(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 format Col1 'MMM-YYYY'",1)
```

Answer (score 1):

within sheets you can try:

```
=QUERY({INDEX(IF(LEN(A9:A),EOMONTH(A9:A,),)),C9:C},"SELECT Col1, SUM(Col2) Where Col1 IS NOT NULL GROUP BY Col1 LABEL SUM(Col2) '' FORMAT Col1 'MMM YY'")
```

- 

[image]

Comment: you need to clear the cells down the line & allow the array result to expand freely down the line.

Comment: Yes. It made my work so easy. i was literally adding up by ranges. 
Where can i learn such stuff ?  any tutorial you can point me to.

Comment: I mean there's lot of tutorials on YT. this beginners tutorial looks promising (https://youtu.be/TENAbUa-R-w)